# Recursive multidimensional array search but exclude a certain sub-array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code. Basically I want to search through the keys of this multidimensional array from top to bottom, but ignore the sub-array with the key specified by `$ignoreKey`. As you can see by the `"array_key_exists"` logic, it is currently built for a 1D array.. I tried some examples but having problems (so have left my 1D code as is below).

If all went as planned, I would have `"thirtyfromgroup1"` echoed.

What would I have to change in the following to achieve this?

```
$keyCheck = "30";
$ignoreKey = "group2";

if (array_key_exists($keyCheck, $topLevel)) {
      echo $topLevel[$keyCheck];
}

 $topLevel = array( 
           "group1" => array
                               (
                               "12" => "twelve", 
                               "30" => "thirtyfromgroup1" 
                               ),
            "group2" => array
                               (
                               "14" => "fourteen", 
                               "30" => "thirty" 
                                ),
             "group3" => array
                               (
                               "12" => "twelve", 
                               "26" => "thirty" 
                                ),
                   );
```

Comment: Do you just want to ignore keys in the top level of the array or sublevels too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just want to ignore keys in the top level of your array, and are just searching the keys in the second level:

```
$keyCheck = "30";
$ignoreKey = "group2";

$topLevel = array( 
    "group1" => array(
        "12" => "twelve", 
        "30" => "thirtyfromgroup1"
    ),
    "group2" => array(
        "14" => "fourteen", 
        "30" => "thirty" 
    ),
    "group3" => array(
        "12" => "twelve", 
        "26" => "thirty" 
    ),
);

foreach($topLevel as $topKey => $topValue)
{
    if ($topKey == $ignoreKey)
        continue;

    foreach($topValue as $subKey => $subValue)
    {
        if ($subKey == $keyCheck)
            echo $subValue;
    }

    /* Alternatively:

    if (isset($topValue[$keyCheck]))
        echo $topValue[$keyCheck];

    */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I can't believe how hard my brain finds multidimensional arrays in php grrr thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a loop for the sub-arrays, instead of just `isset($topValue[$keyCheck])`?

Comment: @Barmar Didn't think about it, added it as an alternative!